# how to clear status from filter search

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning react and specifically trying to filter the data through a search. So far, so good.

When I try to clear the results from the input I'm left with the searched data, while I want to have all the initial data.

How can I solve this problem?

```
import { FC, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import './style.css';

export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [searched, setSearched] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUsers() {
      let response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
      ).then((response) => response.json());
      setUsers(response);
    }
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (searched.length >= 2) {
      async function getUsers() {
        let response = await fetch(
          'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
        ).then((response) => response.json());
        setUsers(
          response.filter((resp) =>
            resp.name.toLowerCase().includes(searched.toLowerCase())
          )
        );
      }
      getUsers();
    }
  }, [searched]);

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter name"
        value={searched}
        onChange={(ev) => setSearched(ev.target.value)}
      />
      {users && users.map((user) => <p>{user.name}</p>)}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are blocking yourself from handling the an empty search string, when you use this condition `if (searched.length >= 2) {`. Remove it to handle short or empty search strings.

However, you also load the same data, and then manually filter it in the component. Instead, load the state once, and filter it in the body of the component:

```
export const App: FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [searched, setSearched] = useState('');
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function getUsers() {
      let response = await fetch(
        'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'
      ).then((response) => response.json());
      setUsers(response);
    }
    getUsers();
  }, []);
  
  const list = searched 
    ? users.filter(resp => resp.name.toLowerCase().includes(searched.toLowerCase());
    : users;

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Enter name"
        value={searched}
        onChange={(ev) => setSearched(ev.target.value)}
      />
      {list && list.map(user => <p>{user.name}</p>)}
    </>
  );
};
```

If the list is long, this would cause performance issues. You might want to look at how debounce or throttle work.

You should also look at the [useTransition](https://react.dev/reference/react/useTransition) hook - [examples](https://blog.greenroots.info/explain-react-18-usetransition-hook-with-examples).

Comment: Where to use 'list'? Also I want all users initially, then when I filter it only shows me the filtered users

Comment: Use `list` instead of `users` when rendering (see updated example) .